# Azure Disk encryption [ADE] extension provisioning failure on VM

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

When I try to encrypt an Azure VM(Windows Server 2016) disk using a key in the key vault, I receive the below error. Can someone suggest what I am missing?

*[{"code":"VMExtensionProvisioningError","message":"VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'AzureDiskEncryption'. Error message: "[2.2.0.45] Failed to enable Azure Disk Encryption on the VM with the following exception details:\n Microsoft.Cis.Security.BitLocker.BitlockerIaasVMExtension.BitlockerFailedToSendEncryptionSettingsException: Unable to find additional details in disk encryption response\r\n   at Microsoft.Cis.Security.BitLocker.BitlockerIaasVMExtension.WireProtocol.WireProtocolMessage.SendEncryptionSettingsToHost() in C:\__w\1\s\src\BitLocker\BitlockerIaasVMExtension\WireProtocol\WireProtocolMessage.cs:line 210\r\n   at Microsoft.Cis.Security.BitLocker.BitlockerIaasVMExtension.BitlockerExtension.SendEncryptionSettingsToHostV3(VmEncryptionSettings vmSettings) in C:\__w\1\s\src\BitLocker\BitlockerIaasVMExtension\BitlockerExtension.cs:line*

Answer (score 0):

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment to encrypt the Azure VM Disks using PowerShell:**

> Make sure that **Connect-AzAccount** with contributor role or owner role to create resources and modify in resource group, and also check if drive is already encrypted with Bitlocker and **Azure Disk Encryption**, Kindly decrypt the drivers before ran the script.

**PowerShell Script to encrypt Azure VM:**

```
#Connect to Azure Account with Contributor role or Admin role.

Connect-AzAccount
```

[image]

**Create a resource group:**

```
New-AzResourceGroup -Name "myResourceGroup" -Location "EastUS"
```

[image]

**Create a Key vault:**

```
New-AzKeyvault -name thejaKVtest -ResourceGroupName myResourceGroup -Location EastUS -EnabledForDiskEncryption
```

[image]

```
#Store the value in Keyvault

$KeyVault = Get-AzKeyVault -VaultName thejaKVtest -ResourceGroupName MyResourceGroup
```

**Encrypt Azure VM:**

```
Set-AzVMDiskEncryptionExtension -ResourceGroupName MyResourceGroup -VMName <YourVM Name> -DiskEncryptionKeyVaultUrl $KeyVault.VaultUri -DiskEncryptionKeyVaultId $KeyVault.ResourceId
```

**Get Azure vm encryption status:**

```
Get-AzVmDiskEncryptionStatus -VMName MyVm -ResourceGroupName MyResourceGroup
```

[image]

If still same error, kindly check the below settings in key vault , like below.

**Azure Portal > Key Vault > Select your Key Vault > Access Configuration > Enable Azure Disk Encryption for volume encryption**

[image]

Reference: [Create and encrypt a Windows virtual machine in Azure with PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/disk-encryption-powershell-quickstart)

Comment: thank you for the info. the Access configuration is all good. I am looking to encrypt using the portal. May be will try using PowerShell as well and see how it goes

Comment: Please refer this link to encrypt Azure VM using Portal: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/disk-encryption-portal-quickstart